# How to check decorators on class declared in an imported file?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, custom-eslint-plugin

I'm trying to make sure that classes given in nestjs providers array of module decorator, have Injectable decorator.

I wrote a custom ESLint rule, which works if the class is declared in the same file, but breaks when the class is declared in another file and is imported.

How do I check decorators on class declared in an imported file?

---

Here's what I tried so far:

```js
module.exports = {
  'injectable-providers': {
    create: function (context) {
      return {
        ClassDeclaration: function (node) {
          const moduleDecorator = nestModule.getModuleDecorator(node);
          if (!moduleDecorator) {
            return;
          }
          const properties = moduleDecorator.expression.arguments[0].properties;
          if (!properties) {
            return;
          }

          const providersProperty = properties.find(
            (property) => property.key.name === 'providers'
          );
          const providers = providersProperty?.value.elements ?? [];

          providers.forEach((provider) => {
            const providerNode = context.getScope().upper.set.get(provider.name)
              ?.defs[0]?.node;
            if (providerNode && !nestInjectable.isInjectable(providerNode)) {
              context.report({
                message: 'Provider is not `@Injectable`',
                node: provider,
              });
            }
          });
        },
      };
    },
  },
};

const nestModule = {
  getModuleDecorator: (node) =>
    node?.decorators?.find(
      (decorator) => decorator.expression.callee.name === 'Module'
    ),
};

const nestInjectable = {
  isInjectable: (node) => {
    const isClass = node?.type === 'ClassDeclaration';
    const hasInjectableDecorator = (node?.decorators ?? []).some(
      (decorator) => decorator.expression.callee.name === 'Injectable'
    );
    return node && isClass && hasInjectableDecorator;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

ESLint rules operate solely on single-files. They cannot access information from other files.

That being said, you can make the rule a type-aware rule, which will allow you to access TS types and thus inspect information across files.

https://typescript-eslint.io/custom-rules/#typed-rules